# Perform Selector With Object in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, selector, ios10

I am trying to perform selector with object in **swift 3.0**

I have a selector which have one parameter

`func imageSelected(aImage : UIImage)`

and I am calling it like

`viewC.perform(Selector.init("imageSelected:"), with: image, afterDelay: 0.1)`

But the app crashes with error that the selector is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It started working well as, I modified the selector being called

from

```
func imageSelected(aImage : UIImage)
```

to this

```
func imageSelected(_ aImage : UIImage)
```

Comment: Thanks to all, for quick help here

Comment: There is no need to add `_` as first parameter label you can still access it using `aImage` the problem is you need to add the Your class name also with your method.

Answer (score 9):

Here's something I always do when I encounter selectors in swift: Ignore the parameters, just use the name.

You used this:

```
imageSelected:
```

What is that `:` doing there? Delete it! Just use the name of the method!

Also, there is this great `#selector` syntactic sugar, please use that:

```
viewC.perform(#selector(imageSelected), with: image, afterDelay: 0.1)
```

Comment: The synthetic sugar is lovely, but this method contains a bug in Xcode10/macOS 10.13: whatever CGPoint I pass in ends up as (0.0, 9.223372036854776e+18). Just putting this here so save someone else a lot of headaches. 
The solution is to set a temporary variable and to access it directly in the delayed function. (Other objects passed as parameters seem just fine.)

Answer (score 7):

This is for swift 4.0

```
perform(#selector(yourMethodHere), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
```

Add @objc flag before your function

```
@objc public func yourMethodHere(){
     //your code here
}
```