# How access superclass property with key-value coding?

Tags: swift, super, key-value-coding

Is it possible to access an object's superclass's property using key-value coding?

I tried something like this:

```
class Bar: Foo {
    var shouldOverridePropertyOfFoo: Bool = false

    var propertyOfFoo: String {
        if shouldOverrideProperty {
            return "property of Bar"
        } else {
            return value(forKeyPath: "super.propertyOfFoo") as! String
        }
    }
}
```

But, I got this runtime error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '`[<MyModule.Bar 0x2da2cf003e00> valueForUndefinedKey:]`: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key `super`.'

Note: I'm trying to figure out [how to override private method and call super in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228647/how-to-override-private-method-and-call-super-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `super.aPropertyOfFoo`, you have to use `Foo.aPropertyOfFoo`, which is better done with `#keyPath`s instead of `Strings`:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc var aPropertyOfFoo = "property of foo"
}

class Bar: Foo {
    var shouldOverridePropertyOfFoo: Bool = false

    var propertyOfFoo: String {
        if shouldOverridePropertyOfFoo {
            return "property of bar"
        } else {
            return value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(Foo.aPropertyOfFoo)) as! String
        }
    }
}

let bar = Bar()
print(bar.propertyOfFoo) // "property of foo"
```